# Sorting vector of pointers complexity

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, time-complexity

For education purpose. What is the complexity of sorting array/vector?

Typical sort has n log n, is sorting pointers faster?

Comment: What is the use case for sorting pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting will always be the same complexity... You mean sorting an array filled with pointers to things you want to sort?

Sometimes it might be faster (faster execution, not complexity). This is because changing places of pointers may be faster than changing places of some complex objects.